# Cross Table between all variables calculation in R

Tags: r, dataframe, crosstab

I need perform crosstable between one variable and another.
In my case between Save.cluster and other variables in the dataset.
I can do that (each variable-new string).

```
library('gmodels')
d <- CrossTable(iris1$Save.cluster, iris1$elements, expected = TRUE)
d <- CrossTable(iris1$Save.cluster, iris1$var3, expected = TRUE)
d <- CrossTable(iris1$Save.cluster, iris1$var4, expected = TRUE)
```

But I have so many variables(100), and create 100 strings is not good idea.
How can i perform crosstable between Save.cluster and another 100 variables at once.
Here there reproducible example
iris 1

```
structure(list(var1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), var2 = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), var3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), var4 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), var5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), save.cluster = 0:5), .Names = c("var1", 
"var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "save.cluster"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Do you really need to store the results in an object? How about `apply(iris1[,-1], 2, function(x) CrossTable(iris1[["save.cluster"]], x, expected = TRUE))`?

Comment: well, very good, but how can i export output to csv file?